# Formulating a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do we write a formula for the following sequence?

$a_n = 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5...$

I have been trying for some time now and till have very little idea as to how to proceed.

Comment: Did you notice the reflection pattern?

Comment: @Solitary yeah but i'm not sure how to use it

Comment: $a_0=1, a_1=2, a_2=3, a_3=2,a_4=1\dots$ and that way?

Comment: @MonsieurGalois I am fully aware of what $a_0$ to $a_4$ should equal, what should $a_i$ equal?

Comment: I meant if the sequence is that or the list of numbers is the first element. But now I understand that each one is an element of the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically a sequence of triangular waves of different size. Well, find the size of the k'th wave, then the sum of the first k waves, then reverse that (there is going to be a quadratic equation along the way) to get $k$ (the number of the wave you are in) from $n$, then define the shape of that wave.

> $$a_n=2k+3-|n-(k+1)(2k+3)|,\text{ where }k=\left\lfloor\sqrt{{n\over2}+{1\over16}}-{3\over4}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: Very cleverly expressed !

Answer (score 0):

Given an odd number $2k + 1$, $\{1, 2, \ldots, 2k\}$ is reflected about it. So to formulate this sequence, we first need to stipulate the positions of odd numbers $3, 5, 7, \ldots$. For a fixed odd number $2k + 1, k = 1, 2, 3,  \ldots$, there are 
$$2k + 2 \times [(2k - 2) + \cdots + 2] + (k - 1) = 2k^2 + k - 1$$
terms precede it. Therefore
$$a_{2k^2 + k} = 2k + 1, k = 1, 2, \ldots.$$
For integer $j$ such that $2k^2 + k  < j < 2(k + 1)^2 + (k + 1)$, it is clear that if $2k^2 + k + 1 \leq j \leq 2k^2 + k + 2k$, then
$$a_{j} = (2k + 1) - [j - (2k^2 + k)] = 2k^2 + 3k - j + 1;$$
if $2k^2 + k  + 2k + 1 \leq j \leq 2(k + 1)^2 + (k + 1) - 1$, then 
$$a_{j} = (2k + 3) - [2(k + 1)^2 + (k + 1) - j] = j - 2(k + 1)^2 + k + 2.$$

In summary, we conclude (note that in my notation, $a_1$, instead of $a_0$, is the initial term of sequence) that $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2$ and for $n \geq 3$:
$$
a_n = 
\begin{cases}
2k + 1 & n = 2k^2 + k; \\
2k^2 + 3k - n + 1 & 2k^2 + k + 1 \leq n \leq 2k^2 + 3k; \\
n - 2(k + 1)^2 + k + 2 & 2k^2 + 3k + 1 \leq n \leq 2(k + 1)^2 + k.
\end{cases} \tag{1}$$

$(1)$ should be used in this way: if there exists some $k \in \{1, 2, \ldots\}$ such that $n = 2k^2 + k$, then $a_n$ is given by the first row of $(1)$. Otherwise, there exists some $k \in \{1, 2, \ldots\}$ such that either $2k^2 + k + 1 \leq n \leq 2k^2 + 3k$ or $2k^2 + 3k + 1 \leq n \leq 2(k + 1)^2 + k$, for the former case we use the second row of $(1)$ to compute $a_n$ and for the latter case we use the third row of $(1)$ to compute $a_n$.